# getting HTTP Status 500 while running tomcat

Tags: java

```
    HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

Comment: I think you should check your dependencies / added JARs. "It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" says there is some class used by another class and the class cannot be found.

Comment: Add the jsp which is getting compilation error

Comment: Error on your JSP page and Check your JAR File as well

Comment: Check if "rt.jar" is available ...

Comment: I am just running the tomcat server and checking if its running or not in browser by entering localhost:8080 and its giving the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you are using apache-tomcat-7.0.27.  That version doesn't have support for JDK8 so you need to upgrade to a newer version.  I know that apache-tomcat-7.0.50 supports for JDK8.

The class format of JDK8 has changed and thats the reason why Tomcat is not able to compile JSPs.

Comment: could you please give me the link to download apache-tomcat-7.0.50

Comment: Here you can find all 7 versions.  Maybe you prefer to get a newer one: http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/

Comment: I think so, try and check it